# Where to place layout file in a name-spaced app’s directory structure?

Tags: php, templates, namespaces, directory-structure

So I have a PHP application I’m developing that’s nicely name-spaced as such:

```
src/
    VendorName/
        Ecommerce/
            Products/
                Controllers/
                    ProductsController.php
                Models/
                    Product.php
                Views/
                    index.html
                    view.html
```

Straightforward. My project is an e-commerce website, with functionality broken down into sub-modules like `Products`, `Cart`, `Discounts` etc. Each module then has its own controllers, models, and HTML view files.

My question is, although modules have their own views, where would I put “global” template files, like a common layout?

Comment: "Nicely" is overstating a bit.  If i have to go 3 levels down just to find a tree of anything, you've kinda overdone it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I find this structure works and is employed by frameworks such as Symfony and Zend Framework. There’s a top-level vendor name to avoid collisions, an application name, and then modules within an application.

Comment: Are building your own MVC framework? Then you can keep anywhere you want. But my suggestion is to keep inside src/ so that all module can access with same path level. Or even you can define a path to access common view.

Comment: I obviously want to keep it in my `src` directory, but trying to decide best place *under* my `src` directory.

Comment: short answer: in the "templates" folder.